# Calculating a payment price based on a selected phone

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented

The program shows three phones with prices, and you need to select one of them. The program will then calculate the price based on the payment type you selected.

I'm very new to the world of OOP, and because I'm studying OOP on my own (I actually go to school and we have a computer subject, but I'm taking advance lessons on my own), I have no one to judge my code. I can make programs run, but I'm not sure if I am coding well.

Is there a better way I could have written this simple program? What are the conventions that I did not follow? I did my best based on things I read though, but I'm not sure if I missed things.

```
package javaPackage;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class OopApproach 
{
    private String model;
    private double price;
    private double discount;

    public OopApproach(String model,int price)
    {
        this.model=model;
        this.price=price;
    }
    public void setModel( String model )
    {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public void setPrice( double price )
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    { 
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int selection;

        OopApproach iPhone = new OopApproach( "iPhone 6s", 299);
        OopApproach samsung = new OopApproach( "Samsung s6", 199);
        OopApproach lg = new OopApproach( "LG", 99 );

        System.out.println("Press 1:" + iPhone.model+" = " + "$" + df.format(iPhone.price));
        System.out.println("Press 2:" + samsung.model+" = " + "$" +df.format(samsung.price));
        System.out.println("Press 3:" + cherry.model+" = "+ "$" + df.format(lg.price));

        selection=input.nextInt();

        switch(selection)
        {
        case 1:System.out.println( "Your item is " + iPhone.model + " with price of " + "$" + df.format(iPhone.price));
        System.out.println();
        calcPrice(iPhone.model, iPhone.price); 
        break;
        case 2:System.out.println( "Your item is " + samsung.model + " with price of " + "$" + df.format(samsung.price));
        System.out.println();
        calcPrice(samsung.model, samsung.price);
        break;
        case 3:System.out.println( "Your item is " + lg.model + " with price of " + "$" + df.format(lg.price));
        System.out.println();
        calcPrice(cherry.model, lg.price);
        break;
        }
    }
        public static void calcPrice(String model,double price)
        {
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            DecimalFormat dff=new DecimalFormat("##.00");
            int selec;
            double totalVal;

            System.out.println("Choose payment option");
            System.out.println("1:Cash - 5% discount");
            System.out.println("2:Installment, 3 months - 5% interest");
            System.out.println("3:Installment, 6 months - 10% interest");

            selec=in.nextInt();

            if(selec==1)
            {
                totalVal=price-(price*.05);
                System.out.print("You purchased " + model + " and the total cost is "+ "$" + dff.format(totalVal));
            }
            else if(selec==2)
            {
                totalVal=price+(price*.05);
                System.out.print("You purchased " + model + " and the total cost is "+ "$" + dff.format(totalVal));
            }
            else if(selec==3)
            {
                totalVal=price+(price*.10);
                System.out.print("You purchased " + model + " and the total cost is "+ "$" + dff.format(totalVal));
            }
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Press 1:iPhone 6s = $299.00
> Press 2:Samsung s6 = $199.00
> Press 3:LG = $99.00
> 1
> Your item is iPhone 6s with price of $299.00
>
> Choose payment option
> 1:Cash - 5% discount
> 2:Installment, 3 months - 5% interest
> 3:Installment, 6 months - 10% interest
> 1
>  You purchased iPhone 6s and the total cost is $284.05
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You have seemed to start off ok, by acknowledging that you need an object to hold the *price* and *name* of the phone.

You can separate this object's class, as others have mentioned, into another file and give it a more meaningful name (e.g. MobilePhone, Device, etc.)

Going back to the original problem, you need to calculate the final purchase price of a phone. According to your requirements, this final value might be influenced by the type of payment the user chooses (e.g Cash or Credit)

There's several ways you can approach your problem afterwards.

## Example:

You can have an object that is responsible for calculating the final price of a phone based on the payment options. This might require you to create objects for the payment options as well.

*(code below is missing some parts, like constructors, etc)*

```
class PhonePriceCalculator {
    public double calcPrice(Phone phone, Cash cash) { }
    public double calcPrice(Phone phone, Credit cash) { }
}

// some classes to hold data
class Phone { }
class Cash { }
class Credit { }
```

Then, you just need to plug those objects in with your `main()` method. There are some improvements that you can make to code above.

For example, `Cash` is really just a type placeholder for calculating price. It never changes. Maybe you can model the `Cash` and `Credit` options through an [enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). This will work just fine if there's only two credit types.

## Another example:

Maybe modelling the price calculation through an object isn't so bad. But you didn't like the fact that we also have objects for the payment types (or an `Enum` if you decided to go for that instead). Well, you can simplify the price calculator by giving it a discount value instead:

```
class PhonePriceCalculator {
    public double calcPrice(Phone phone, double discount) { }
}
```

This way, this class doesn't need to know the payment type. Just the discount.

## Final Considerations

I didn't touch private/public encapsulation because other users like Pimgd and Ethan Bierlien had already mentioned it. But again, it is wise to make fields inside an object private, and expose them through methods. Remember, the object is the *owner* of those fields. **So it must choose to expose them (or not) consciously.**

I know this is a toy example, but when you are dealing with money calculations in java, you're better of using the [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead of `double`. You can play with decimal scales, amongst other things.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to consider all your answers and edit my code. I'm going to post a revision as an answer later.

Comment: @JohnQuasar if you do that, be sure to explain why you made the changes, as otherwise, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when programming in an Object Oriented manner, you work with objects. So you should make a class `Phone` instead of "OopApproach".

Second, if you move your main out of the class `OopApproach`, you'll find that you can't access `phone.model` and the other variables. For that reason, you'll have to make it accessible in some manner.

Now, there's two choices for this:

First option is to add getters and setters (you've already added the setters, just the getters left). The nice thing about that is that you can modify the way properties are accessed or even return default values in place of null.

The second option is to make the related properties public. I tend to call these 'Data Objects', and if you're from C, they're pretty much structs. Those classes usually have no methods - all they do is get constructed and hold data.

Once you're working with Phone objects that have getters, you can rewrite this method

```
public static void calcPrice(String model,double price)
```

To use a `Phone` instead:

```
public static void calcPrice(Phone phone)
```

and you can use the getters to obtain the values.

Comment: might expand on this later but I had to leave

Answer (score 2):

There are many things that you're doing wrong here. To start off, your main method needs to be in a separate class from `OopApproach`, as `OopApproach` is intended to model a phone and not run code. You should create a separate class like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        // Run code here.
    }
}
```

Next, why is the `calcPrice` method `static`? If it's already attached to the object modeling a phone (`OopApproach`), then it should be non-static, and not take any parameters, like this:

```
public void calcPrice() {
    // Calculate the price based on payment option.
}
```

But, that's not all. Next you're going to have to change all `model` and `price` references in `calcPrice` to `this.model` and `this.price`. Now `calcPrice` is no longer a static method, and you will be able to run it from any instance of `OopApproach`.

Pimgd already touched on this a bit, but you should probably change your private fields to public fields and remove the extraneous setters. In something as trivial as this, getters and setters aren't really needed. When you have larger code that requires more logic for getting and setting fields, then use getters and setters.

Finally, I have just a few nitpicks to cover:

- You need to have more spaces between operators. For example, `totalVal=price+(price*.05);` would become `totalVal = price + (price * .05);`, or `selec==3` to `selec == 3`. The extra spaces make your code much easier to read.
- `OopApproach` should be named something better, like `CellularDevice`, or `MobilePhone`.
- You need to use better variable names. Names like `in`, `dff`, or `selec` don't describe what a variable does. Names should be descriptive and convey a variable's purpose clearly.